# Distriqt ANE Crashes When Using Adobe Air Sdk 15.0

Tags: air, flash-builder

I'm using InAppBilling ANE and AIR 15 crashes. Flash Builder can't create swf file when add ane extension.

There is the error below,

Process terminated unexpectedly.

The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Requested extension com.distriqt.InAppBilling could not be found.

Launch command details: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0 with Air 15.0\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0 with Air 15.0\runtimes\air\win" -profile mobileDevice -screensize 320x455:320x480 -XscreenDPI 181 -XversionPlatform AND "C:\Users\Saygın Karahan\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Albatros\bin-debug\Root-app.xml" "C:\Users\Saygın Karahan\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Albatros\bin-debug"

Comment: @Michael https://distriqt.uservoice.com/forums/199650-general/suggestions/6460257-recompile-your-ane-files-for-use-with-air-15-they

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you added your .ane in your project or not.

If you not added means, follow these steps to add .ane in your project.

At First, when we use .ane in flex project, we should add the .ane file for packaging.

1. Right click - in your project
2. Choose Properties
3. Select - Flex Build Path in left side menu.
4. Choose - Native Extension tab
5. The click Add ANE button to browse your .ane file in your system. - Here you added your .ane file into your project.

But this is not enough steps to use .ane. You should add your .ane file into your packaging, then only the release build will having the support from that .ane file.

6. Go To - Flex Build Packaging - in properties window.
   Here, we have two options, One for Apple IOS, and Google Android.
7. Choose, for which device you are going to use.
8. After choosing that options, you having the tab Native Extension in right side.
9. Your added .ane file is showing in the below ANE Details data grid.
10. Select the check box to adding that ane file into the packaging.

Here, you can verify that ane file, which platform that ane going to support.

An alert will prompt you for confirmation, click yes, then click OK in properties window.

Now, you added your.ane file in your project.

Finally, Check your descriptor file with the  tag. The added .ane package path is added in the `<extensionID>` tag.

```
<extensions>
    <extensionID>ane package path</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

**Note :** When you using any .ane in your project, simulator is not support to run your application

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the extension is included in the packaging options on the platform you are using?

Have a look at the getting started tutorial:

http://airnativeextensions.com/knowledgebase/tutorial/1

In particular:

Go to project settings, and to the "Build Packaging" for the platforms you are deploying and check the extension is going to be packaged (and available) with them (small checkbox on the right of the extension).